# How to input generated CAPTCHA Text in text field using cypress test?

Tags: automated-tests, cypress

How to input generated CAPTCHA Text in text field using cypress test.
I need a example script_spec.js enters email, passsword and CAPTCHA Text for successfully login

```
//Home page
  cy.visit('http://someurl.com');

//Login
  cy.contains('Log in').click();
  cy.url().should('eq', 'http://someurl.com'); // => true
  cy.get('#Email').type('me@url.com');
  cy.get('#Password').type('password');

//Enter CAPTCHA Text in text field here(TODO..)

  cy.contains('Log In').click();
//SUCESSFULLY
 cy.url().should('eq', 'http://someurl.com'); // => Home page true
```

[image]

Comment: Do you know what the captcha will be ahead of time? What does your HTML look like? What issue are you running into when you attempt to input the captcha?

Comment: No it's auto generated, also has button to generate yourself                          <div>
        <img id="CaptchaImage" src="/MMSQA/DefaultCaptcha/Generate? 
              t=ce557b86d1584297916ff5ce3f21391f" style="width:280px;">

        <input id="CaptchaDeText" name="CaptchaDeText" type="hidden" 
           value="ce557b86d1584297916ff5ce3f21391f" autocomplete="off">
</div>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would have an environmental variable in your backend (ex ENV=test). When you run the application pass in that environmental variable. And where the capcha validatation happens do

```
passed = ENV===‘test’ || actualValidation
```

So whatever you pass it in the test environment it will accept. Then just pass it “anyrandomvalue”.

In production it will fall back to actual validation