# How can I make a Cypress test score as a bot with reCAPTCHA v3?

Tags: bots, cypress, recaptcha, captcha

I have an automated test with cypress and js that interacts with a web form, which has now been implemented with recaptcha v3. I thought the recaptcha would recognize the cypress test and score it as a bot (score <= 0.5) but it didn't.

Can I make the cypress test purposefully score as a bot after completing the form input, is there a command or setting for it?

Code section:

```
When('El usuario completa su DNI {string}',(dni)=>{
    homePage.getInputDNI().type(dni)
});
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to input generated CAPTCHA Text in text field using cypress test?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52037400/how-to-input-generated-captcha-text-in-text-field-using-cypress-test)